# How to make api.ai agent learn something dynamically?

Tags: android, json, nlp, artificial-intelligence, dialogflow-es

I am currently using api.ai , to create agent to perform specific tasks, but one question i don't have answer to is , can i make it learn something while chatting , mean that i speak **my name is 'John Cena'** and she should store it and then whenever i ask her again bot should answer me that. i know there is a way to do it by logging into **api.ai** web and manually add entries , but it will not help, is there any work around programmatically or automatically ?  the file i've been using to practice is given in [github](https://github.com/sitepoint-editors/Api-AI-Personal-Assistant-Demo/blob/master/index.html) . and here is working [DEMO](http://patcat.com/demos/barry/)

Answer (score 4):

You basically need for your bot to "learn" facts.  There are many different ways to achieve this, but recently the most common way is to arrange knowledge into Semantic "Triples" and store the knowledge into a Graph repository (like Neo4j, Titan, Spark Graph, etc).  In your example, "my name is John Cena" would translate into a Triple like ("anubava","Name","John Cena").  That  way, the next time you are logged in as anubhava and ask "What is my name?", it would translate into a Graph search that will return "John Cena".  A word of caution, achieving this is not trivial and would require some significant amount of fine tuning.   For more info, you can check [here](http://linkeddata.org/) and [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/).

Finally, most complete solutions (that I know of), are Server Side solutions.  If you want for the whole knowledge base to reside in your mobile device,  you could probably use the resources there as inspiration, and build your own Linked Data repository using an embedded database.

Hope this helps.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

To store and recall the user's name, you'll need to set up a webhook with some basic data persistence capabilities. Any database or key-value store would work fine.

Here's the breakdown:

1. Implement webhook fulfillment for the intent that captures the user's name. The webhook should store the name along with a unique, identifying ID that you should supply from your front-end in either the `sessionId` or as a context parameter in your call to `/query`.
2. Implement webhook fulfillment for the intent that reads the user's name. The webhook should look up the name by ID and return a response that tells the user their name.

The high-level docs for writing a fulfillment webhook are here:

https://docs.api.ai/docs/webhook